# Functions whose distributional second derivative is finite

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (not necessarily continuous) such that $$\operatorname{sup} \left\{\int\limits f(x)\phi'(x)dx: \phi\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}), \|\phi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1 \right\} < \infty.$$
In otherwords, distributional derivative of $f$ is a finite Radon measure.
Then such functions satisfy the following
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\leq Ch  \quad \text{for all } h\geq 0.\label{1}\tag{1}$$

Similarly, can we characterise functions in some $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfy
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)|dx \leq Ch^2 \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
for all  $h\geq 0?$
For example, suppose we assume
$$\operatorname{sup} \left\{\int\limits f(x)\phi''(x)dx: \phi\in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}), \|\phi\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1 \right\}< \infty,$$
then do we get \eqref{2}?

P.S.: Functions in $C_c^1(\mathbb{R})\cap W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_c^2(\mathbb{R})\cap W^{2,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$  satisfy \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} respectively. But I am looking for a more general class of functions(not necessarily continuous).

Comment: I think these are Besov spaces